# Reading ref cursor as output parameter in a stored procedure with spring data jpa returns null

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, sys-refcursor

I'm trying to read a refcursor in an oracle stored procedure using spring data jpa and spring boot, the stored procedure runs succesfully but the reference to the returned List is always null.

I tried using Hibernate as a JPA provider and Eclipse Link with no succed, below are the oracle ddl and java code

Oracle Table (I filled the table with some example data)

```
CREATE TABLE role
    (id                             NUMBER(10,0),
    name                           VARCHAR2(255 CHAR))
```

Oracle Stored Procedure

```
PROCEDURE collect_roles (role_list_o OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
    ex EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    OPEN role_list_o FOR SELECT id, name FROM role;
END;
```

pom.xml (the oracle jdbc driver dependency was installed in maven from a local ojdbc7.jar)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gridapp</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>


<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Oracle JDBC driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

application.properties

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off

# Oracle settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:ora_string_conection
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

# HikariCP settings
# spring.datasource.hikari.*

spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=5
```

Role.java

```
package hello;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQuery;
import javax.persistence.ParameterMode;
import javax.persistence.StoredProcedureParameter;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Direction;

@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "findRolesViaProcedure",
    procedureName = "wfactura.collect_roles",
    resultClasses = Role.class,
    parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, name = "role_list_o", type = Void.class)

    })})
@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id @GeneratedValue//
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

RoleRepository.java

```
package hello;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.Procedure;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

interface RoleRepository extends CrudRepository<Role, Serializable> {

    @Procedure(name = "findRolesViaProcedure")
    List<Role> findRolesViaProcedure();

}
```

I call the store procedure with the next line

```
List<Role> roles = repo.findRolesViaProcedure();
```

I modified the stored procedure for inserting values in another table and i realized that the execution was succesfully, but the List roles is null even though there is data in the table.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
type=Void.class
```

to

```
type=ResultSet.Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by switching to version Spring Boot 2.7.3

Answer (score -1):

```
@StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, name = "role_list_o", type = Void.class)
```

Should be modified as : ==>

```
@StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, name = "role_list_o", type = void.class)
```

Comment: Did it work for you? Because i have the same problem and this solution is not resolving the problem

Comment: I have the same problem you. I cannot call pakage directly in the oracle database. I have to create a new procedure to call pakage. Sorry for my English not good. Because I use translate.